# Gitlab-ci won't replace my variables in curl

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this script in my gitlab yml file:

[image: curl]

```yaml
script:
      - "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"tag\":\"${CI_COMMIT_TAG}\", \"projectId\":\"${PROJECT_ID}\"}' http://localhost:1337/slack"**
```

Let's say when I create a tag named '`testing-v1`' on gitlab, the variables `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` should be '`testing-v1`', but instead it is showing as it is.
It's not replacing.

If I hard code the tag name and project id like this

```
- "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"tag\":\"testing-v1\", \"projectId\":\"1111111\"}' http://localhost:1337/slack"**
```

It's working.

Answer (score 3):

If you copy-paste your `curl` line (without the first and last double-quote) in [`shellcheck.net`](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you will be pointed to [`SC2016`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2016)

> ## Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
>
> Single quotes prevent expansion of everything, including variables and command substitution.
>
> If you want to use the values of variables and such, use double quotes instead.
> Note that if you have other items that needs single quoting, you can use both in a single word:
>
> ```
> echo '$1 USD is '"$rate GBP"
> ```

See an example of a [working `gitlab-ci.yml` with curl here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/4781#note_171802683):

```yaml
image: ruby:2.3
stages:
  - clear-cache

  CLOUDFLARE_URL: https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$zone/purge_cache
  EMAIL: "X-Auth-Email: $email"
  AUTH:  "X-Auth-Key: $key"
  CONTENT: 'Content-Type: application/json'


clear-cache:
  stage: clear-cache
  script:
  - curl -X POST "${CLOUDFLARE_URL}" -H "${EMAIL}" -H "${AUTH}" -H "${CONTENT}" --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer, but still it does not work.

Comment: @DreamSpec what error message do you get?

Comment: There is no error message, but I am using that request body (curl) to send another GET request from Node.js server, but the tag and project id is coming as undefined